# Windows 8 Touch and Dual Monitors

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, touchscreen

Moving to Windows 8 in the near future and I love the whole touch screen aspect of it. I plan to use it at my office with dual monitors.

Question is: If I have two monitors, can only one of them be touch enabled?

I doubt I have the budget to afford two touch monitors, so I am hoping I can still use touch functionality when I want on one monitor and still have mouse functionality on the other.

Comment: I have three touch monitors that I used successfully with Win7. I'm now having problems with Win8. Touch accuracy on the primary monitor is much improved but now ALL of the monitors touch inputs only affect the primary screen. Touch input for items on the secondary monitors does not work. I'm hoping it's a driver issue but I haven't found any definitive resolution so far. For my use this is a HUGE step backwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I have two monitors, can only one of them be touch enabled?

[Yes. Windows 8 is in fact enhanced for multiple monitors.](https://web.archive.org/web/20151122031120/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/b8/archive/2012/05/21/enhancing-windows-8-for-multiple-monitors.aspx)